# Allow tus-ruby-server to save file records to database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, file-upload

As of now, I have a file upload API using Shrine to handle file attachments and I have added `tus-ruby-server` to the mix to add the ability to resume uploads.

I have followed the steps [here](https://github.com/janko-m/shrine-tus-demo) to make it so that when a file is uploaded from `tus-ruby-server`'s endpoint, a database record is also created using Shrine's file handling.

When I POST a file directly to my API's uploads endpoint, it sends the JSON data like so:

```
{"video"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f811d1d5920 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170517-19364-6pfr0g.webm>, @original_filename="video.webm", @content_type="video/webm", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video\"; filename=\"video.webm\"\r\nContent-Type: video/webm\r\n">, "id"=>"35"}
```

When I upload a file using `tus` and then POST that generated file data to my API, it sends the following JSON (which fails):

```
{"video"=>"{\"id\":\"http://localhost:3000/files/8794bf67f32d01cabb9416ca9febf3c3\",\"storage\":\"cache\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"video.webm\",\"size\":142288,\"mime_type\":\"\"}}", "id"=>"35"}
```

Is there any indication of what is going wrong here?

---

Here's the JavaScript that handles the uploading (using `tus-js-client`):

```
var upload = new tus.Upload(file, {
        chunkSize: 1024 * 1024,
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/files',
        metadata: {filename: file.name, content_type: file.type},
        onError: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        onProgress: function(bytesSent, bytesTotal) {
            var progress = parseInt(bytesSent / bytesTotal * 100, 10);
            var percentage = progress.toString() + '%';
            console.log(percentage + ' finished');
        },
        onSuccess: function(result) {
            var fileData = {
                id: upload.url,
                storage: 'cache',
                metadata: {
                    filename: upload.file.name.match(/[^\/\\]+$/)[0],
                    size: upload.file.size,
                    mime_type: upload.file.type
                }
            };

            var fileDataJSON = JSON.stringify(fileData);

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('video', fileDataJSON);
            makeXMLHttpRequest('http://localhost:3000/api/uploads/' + gon.currentId, 'PUT', formData);
        }
    });

    console.log('Uploading video recording to server...');
    upload.start();
```

The JavaScript I used before to handle uploading *without* `tus`:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('video', blob, 'video.webm');

makeXMLHttpRequest('http://localhost:3000/api/uploads/' + gon.currentId, 'PUT', formData);
```

Comment: What fails when you upload the file using tus and submit a callback to your endpoint with the JSON uploaded file representation?

Comment: @janko-m it has something to do with the form in which the data is POSTed. When I upload directly via my API's endpoint, the file data is wrapped in some sort of hash format (ActiveRecord's hashed file upload, I do believe) but when I upload using `tus`, it sends it as pure JSON instead, which  then gives me problems when I try to take the JSON and send it to my API endpoint to have a database record of the files uploaded via `tus`. Is there anyway to wrap this JSON in ActiveRecord's file hash?

Comment: I assume you mean multipart upload versus direct upload. With the former you upload the file to the same endpoint where you handle the upload, where with the latter you upload the file separately, and then submit just the uploaded file data to your endpoint (Shrine uses the JSON format for that). That's the fundamental difference which is the whole advantage of direct asynchronous uploads, you want to treat those two cases differently. Shrine's attachment attribute accepts these JSON strings (in addition to regular files), which you can utilize with `Shrine::Attachment` or `Shrine::Attacher`.

Comment: I would suggest using the Shrine mailing list for these kind of questions, as StackOverflow comments are a bit limiting. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ruby-shrine